# Sorting every word in the dictionary with a hash table... linked lists filled with the same word for some reason

Tags: c, hashtable

**Summary**

I'm trying to create a hash table with 26 linked lists, one for each letter. It will take a dictionary and sort each word into one of the 26 linked lists according to its first letter. For example, "acorn" will enter index 0 of the hash table since it starts with a, and ball will enter the second.

Below you will find my c code, my dictionary file (which I read from using fopen and the such), as well as the odd output I'm getting. I've been trying to debug this for hours.

Expected behaviour would be a sorted hash table with every word in the dictionary. What I'm getting is a hash table with linked lists with the correct amount of words, problem is that every word is replaced with "zymurgy", the last word in my dictionary. Please help! I'm happy to give any additional info needed. Also, changing the last word of the dictionary will change the word that replaces everything. For example, changing the last word to "orange" will end up replacing every word with orange.

Thanks so much for reading! It takes will power to make it this far without clicking off.

**Code**

**I know I am leaking lots of memory. This is only one part of a very big file, I free the memory in other parts of the whole program. I configured my program so that I could display only what was important to the question. (Too lazy to free it all)**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char* word;
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    // Find the place the first letter of {word} has in the alphabet (0 based)
    int pos = toupper(word[0]) % 32 - 1;
    return pos;
}

// Appends a node with a string value at the end of a linked list
void append_node(node* current, char* value) {
    if (!current->word) {
        current->word = value;
        return;
    }
    while (current->next) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = malloc(sizeof(node));
    current = current->next;
    current->next = NULL;
    current->word = value;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // Initialize hash table
    const unsigned int N = 26;
    node *table[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        table[i] = malloc(sizeof(node));
        table[i]->word = malloc(45 + 1);
        table[i]->word = NULL;
        table[i]->next = NULL;
    }

    FILE* file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    // There are no words longer than 45 letters, add one for the null terminator
    char* line = malloc(46);

    // Fill hash table
    while (fgets(line, 45, file)) {
        append_node(table[hash(line)], line);
    }

    // Debugging... Outputs like 1000 lines of "zymurgy".
    // Prints the first linked list in the hash table.
    printf("Start\n");
    node* current = table[0];
    while (current->next) {
        printf("%s", current->word);
        current = current->next;
    }

    return false;
}

int main(void) {
    load("dictionaries/large");
    return 0;
}
```

**Dictionary File Snippet**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/raX1V.jpg Please tell me if more of my dictionary is necessary.

**Weird Output**

```
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
zymurgy
... Goes on for a very very long time
```

Comment: `current->word = value;` Since the `value` passed in is the same `line` variable every time the result is not surprising. It means all the nodes point to the same buffer and thus changing the buffer contents changes the value seen by all nodes. Make copies of the string with `current->word = strdup(value)`

Comment: @kaylum Ohhhhhhhhh that makes sense.

Comment: @kaylum Thank you so much!